# Swift detect in the setter which object in an array was changed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, getter-setter

I have an array of Habit objects which I am modifying in memory and a getter/setter to read and write it to documents storage as JSON whenever changes are made. I have split each object into its own JSON file and so far everything works, however changing one object in the array will re-write all the files. I understand this is what I instructed my setter to do, but is there a way to only write the objects in `newValue` that were changed?

```
extension Storage {
    static var habits: [Habit] {
        get { ... }
        set {
            newValue.forEach({
                let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode($0)
                do { try data.write(to: Storage.habitsFolder.appendingPathComponent("habit-\($0.id).json")) }
                catch let error {
                    print("Failed to write Habit \($0.id): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The way I would make a change now is `Storage.habits[0].name = "Some name"`. Which calls the setter, which then re-writes the files for each habit. So I was wondering if there's some way to  detect which part of newValue changed or pass an index to it and only update that file.

Is the only way to go about this to have the array be get-only and use a different method for setting each habit file?

Thank you, and apologies if this is a silly question.

Update: adding Habit class for more context

```
class Habit: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    // MARK: - Properties
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    var notes: String?
    var icon: String
    var repeatPattern: RepeatPattern
    var entries: [HabitEntry]
    var reminders: [Reminder]
    init(id: Int, name: String?, notes: String?, icon: String, entries: [HabitEntry], reminders: [Reminder]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
        self.icon = icon
        self.repeatPattern = RepeatPattern(pattern: 0, startDay: calendar.today, enabledWeekdays: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], expectedTimes: 1)
        self.entries = entries
        self.reminders = reminders
    }
    var description: String { return "Habit id: \(id), named: \(name ?? "nil"), \nnotes: \(notes ?? "nil"), \nicon: \(icon), \nrepeatPattern: \(repeatPattern), \nentries: \(entries), \nreminders: \(String(describing: reminders))" }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to have the json data writing to disk moved to the Habit object?

Comment: Hey @Leo Dabus, so have a method called save() that I call whenever I make a change to a habit? Or is there some nicer way to have each Habit object update its file whenever one of its properties is changed?

Comment: What about if you remove a Habit from your collection it will continue to exist on disk

Comment: Yes, for deleting habits I am specifically using FileManager to remove the corresponding file at the moment.

Comment: You should do it also for changing it

Comment: Add your Habit object declaration to your question

Comment: Ok. So the way I handle that is with one extra line calling FileManager removeItem. But what I'm asking is if there's a way to incorporate this functionality into the Habit class, so whenever I call habit.name or habit.notes it will also call the method to write to disk.

Comment: I added just the declaration. This class is massive and has a load of other methods for calculating streaks and other things as extensions. I could share those too if relevant.

Comment: There is ways to monitor a folder to detect when it changes. Maybe you can simply monitor when  habitsFolder changes and update your array.

Comment: No I mean have the Habit class write a file habit-id.json to this folder whenever its object in memory is changed. For reading the folder I can just use the getter with a computed property and it will always combine all files into an array I can use. It's writing the individual files that I need to figure out.

Comment: I would probably work directly to disk. I will take a look at it later.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the tips, I'll do something like that. I think @aheze's answer answers the question in the title so I'll be accepting that for those who need the difference in an array in the setter in the future.

Comment: Oh sure, if you're open to sharing some tips on how to actually implement this approach, I'd love to hear them. I hope you don't mind the accepted answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223537/discussion-between-cristianmoisei-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a property to store the existing `habits` first

```
class Storage {
    static var existingHabits = [Habit]()
}
```

Then, inside the `set`, see which `Habit`s are new:

```
static var habits: [Habit] {
    get { ... }
    set {

        var habitsToChange = [Habit]()

        if existingHabits.count == 0 { /// it's empty, just write with newValue
            habitsToChange = newValue
        } else {
            let differentIndicies = zip(existingHabits, newValue).enumerated().filter() {
                $1.0 != $1.1
            }.map{$0.0} /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685226/14351818
        
            for index in differentIndicies {
                habitsToChange.append(newValue[index])
            }
        }

        habitsToChange.forEach({ /// loop over the habits that have changed
            do {
                try JSONEncoder().encode($0).write(to: habitsFolder.appendingPathComponent("habit-\($0.id).json"))
            } catch {
                print("Failed to write Habit \($0.id): \(error)")
            }
        })

        existingHabits = newValue /// set existing to the new value
    }
}
```

Comment: why would force try the encode? `try JSONEncoder().encode($0).write....`

Comment: btw `catch let error` is redundant. Just `catch` and get rid of the `localizedDescription`

Comment: some other notes you can't access an instance property from a static property

Comment: Right, I'll fix

Comment: `Storage.existingHabits` is redundant now just `existingHabits` is enough. Same applies for `habitsFolder`

Comment: Thanks. I need to research more about this