# How to detect in which row in table view new data was added Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have a strange scenario, I have a list of events i have or going to attend. The list contains events in the past now and the future.
Eventlist is sorted by date
Now, I want to highlight a particular row where new event is added added with a border

For example event list is  -

1. event name - xxxxx,
   date - 25/08/2021
2. event name - yyyyy,
   date - 26/08/2021
3. event name - uuuu,
   date - 30/08/2021

No I want to add new event say for date 27 august and highlight that particular row

1. event name - xxxxx,
   date - 25/08/2021
2. event name - yyyyy,
   date - 26/08/2021
3. event name - wwww,
   date - 27/08/2021
4. event name - uuuu,
   date - 30/08/2021

Highlight the 3rd row in this case

Any suggestions and helps are appreciated. Please let me know if any clarification regarding question

Comment: Please show some code, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I guess you have an array of events, then compare them? Iterate over them and find when it's different? Do you only have "new/inserted events" to find? Or also deleted events?

Comment: Yes I have array of events. And I am able to add events to specific date. And I need to highlight the particular row to which the new events was added. @Larme

Comment: You needs to think first: Find new items in your array. Highlight it then. For the Highlight, i'd put it into the Model of your UITableView Datasource. Or in an array of new events id (if that's "quicker").

Comment: @Larme How to find the new item in the array?

Comment: Maybe something there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685163/compare-2-arrays-and-list-the-differences-swift might be useful..

Comment: *I am able to add events to specific date*. If so then you know the insertion index. Or at least you know the item. And likely there is a unique property to be able to identify the item in the array.

Answer (score -1):

- First add your whole server data in some `NSMutableArray`.
- The compare your old server `Date` with new `Date`. Check like ( If your New `date` is lower then your old `date` so data will not insert in your `NSMutableArray` but if your date is  Greater then your old `Date` so you `insert` that data after that `index`